# ALSA external plugin and openmp in C++

Tags: openmp, alsa

I'm creaating an ALSA external module using the [gtkIOStream ALSAExternalPlugin class](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/include/ALSA/ALSAExternalPlugin.H).

In my external plugin code, I am calling the necessary openmp calls :

```
  omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());
  printf("omp_get_num_threads()=%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
```

I am also compiling with the necessary openmp flags and libraries (-fopenmp and -gomp).

However when I run my code using "aplay -DexternalPlugin file" the system reports only one thread in use instead of 20 threads.

Am I missing something ?

The linking flags for compiling the external plugin are like so :
-fopenmp -lgomp  -module -avoid-version -export-dynamic -no-undefined

-fopenmp is also in the CPP flags and I can see them at compile time.

Comment: Operating system? Compiler? Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the number of threads does not make your code go parallel, so, as written, you are setting the number of threads which will be used by the next parallel region, and then printing the number of threads currently in use, which will, indeed, be one, since you haven't gone parallel.

In general, there is no point in forcing the number of threads, since any sane OpenMP runtime (certainly GCC and LLVM) will use all of the available threads by default.

Just print `omp_get_max_threads()` to see what will be used.

Of course, looking at machine load externally when running your code is also a way to check this!

Comment: I ended up using a pragma for statement to make some of the code go in parallel.